# 'submit' is undefined error in browser console

Tags: javascript

I'm coming across an odd issue, I've had this web application running for a few years now and only since people started using IE9 they get the below error. Has been working fine in IE6, 7 & 8.

> 'submit' is undefined

The code being used is this:

```
<a name="SaveButton" id="SaveButton" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('action').value='validate'; submit();" href="#" >Save</a>
```

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Update:
When I change it to this it seems to work find in IE9.

```
<a name="SaveButton" id="SaveButton" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('action').value='validate'; formname.submit();" href="#" >Save</a>
```

*formname is the name of the form being submitted.

Comment: where is `submit` exactly defined?

Comment: What give `console.log(submit)` in the chrome dev box ?

Comment: Can you locate the "Submit" function is your javascript code?

Comment: Seems to work grand in IE9 when I put the form id in front of the submit() function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was due to IE9 not liking the submit() function call coming from an A HREF tag, it should really be used in an INPUT or BUTTON tag.

The way around this due to not being able to modify the majority of the codebase was to add in the form name just before the submit function call like below:

```
formname.submit();
```

Final, working code:

```
<a name="SaveButton" id="SaveButton" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('action').value='validate'; formname.submit();" href="#" >Save</a>
```

The onclick function now works in all IE versions it used to and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

submit function in JavaScript is valid for form element. So this code is invalid , and only somehow works in older internet explorer.

For buttons or inputs the correct syntax is `this.form.submit()`

Comment: Except the attribute is on an `<a>`, so `this.form` will be _undefined_ here

Comment: I wrote that it is for buttons and inputs